# How can I show model information inside another model? in django

Tags: django

So, I have three models , and there are connected with foreign key.
I'm using list_display on "avaria" , and I want to show the name of the "pavimento" inside of the model "avaria". What is the best options to that?

```
class pavimento(models.Model):
  pavimento_nome = models.CharField("Pavimento",max_length=200)

class avaria(models.Model):
  avaria_consumidores = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,verbose_name="Consumidores")



class pavimentacao(models.Model):

  pavimentacao_id=models.ForeignKey(avaria,related_name='avariaObjects',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  pavimentacao_avaria = models.ForeignKey(pavimento,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Pavimento")
```

Comment: Your `avaria` can be related to several `pavimentacao` and as with several `pavimento`. As `pavimentacao` can have one `avaria` but `avaria` can have several `pavimentacao`. Do you want to show all names? Also as a note your fields seem to use wrong Foreight keys. You have `pavimentacao_id` for `avaria` and `pavimentacao_avaria` for `pavimento`.

Comment: @Sergey Pugach , when i start the project , i was having  a N-N relationship, (one `avaria` can have more than one `pavimento`, and one `pavimento` can have more than one `avaria`) , so i create  the `pavimentacao`  to link `avaria` and `pavimento`. But now i want to display inside of `avaria` , the name of the 'pavimento' . For example: If `avaria` have 2 `pavimento`, i want to show the name of the 2 `pavimento`.

Comment: So if I get you right you if you have 2 `pavimento` linked to one `avaria` you need both names to be listed like: `name1, name2`?

Comment: @SergeyPugach Yes, exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a property for `avaria`

```
@property
def pavimento_names(self):
    pavimentacaos = self.avariaObjects.select_related('pavimentacao_avaria').values_list('pavimentacao_avaria__pavimento_nome', flat=True)
    return ', '.join(pavimentacaos)
```

And add `'pavimento_names'` both to `readonly_fields` and `list_display` lists of `avaria` admin.

Or you can directly add method into your admin like:

```
class AvariaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'get_pavimento_names')

    def get_pavimento_names(self, obj):
        pavimentacaos = obj.avariaObjects.select_related('pavimentacao_avaria').values_list('pavimentacao_avaria__pavimento_nome', flat=True)
        return ', '.join(pavimentacaos)
    get_pavimento_names.short_description = 'Pavimento Names'
    get_pavimento_names.admin_order_field = 'avariaObjects__pavimentacao_avaria__pavimento_nome'
```

Comment: This is VERY inefficient. You should use a combination of `queryset.values_list()` and `select_related` or `prefetch_related` to put less load on the db and avoid the overhead of uselessly building full model instances.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers , can you be more explicit please, i can't see how i can do it

Comment: @PedroMariz Sergey just edited his answer according to my suggestions.

Comment: @SergeyPugach, well i am getting this error:`'avariaAdmin' object has no attribute 'avariaObjects'`

Comment: @PedroMariz just change `self` to `obj` there. See edited answer.

Comment: @SergeyPugach thank's mate , just one more question , i can do it the same to the list_filter?

Comment: you can try just `list_filter = ('avariaObjects__pavimentacao_avaria__pavimento_nome',)` for setting list filter

Comment: @SergeyPugach thank's mate , i have another question that no one answer yet, so if you got time , i appreciated, you are the best.